# how to set attribute using javascript variable

Tags: javascript, razor

the following is my cshtml code inside durandal application

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/require.js" 
  id="countryscript" data-main="**here i have to set value**"></script>
```

I want to set script attribute **data-main** with my javascript variable value. How to achieve this ?

I tried as

```
document.getElementById("countryscript").data-main = countrycode;
```

its showing syntax error near **=** sign. Need help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("countryscript").setAttribute("data-main", countrycode);
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute)

```
var d = document.getElementById("countryscript"); 
d.setAttribute("data-main", countrycod);
```

Or if you have JQuery, this is much easier

```
$('#countryscript').attr("data-main", countrycod);
```