# How to change a property in a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a part of a div with Javascript, I was thinking in access to a specific part of a div with `getelementByID` property, but I don't know if this is possible.

This is a facebook like page, and I have more page then I want know if i can change the "data-href" property with javascript for add more different pages.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/petsandfashion?fref=ts" data-width="400" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I don't know if I was clear with the question.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What part of the div were you hoping to access?

Comment: what do you exactly want. Do you only need to change `data-href' attribute value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960932/how-to-set-attribute-using-javascript-variable

Comment: you cant use getElementbyId as your div doesnt have an Id. Are you using jQuery in your page? if yes, try `$('.fb-like').attr( 'data-href','http://....');`

Comment: I want acces to the "data-href", I want put other links in this space.

Comment: No I'm not using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(element_id).setAttribute("data-href", new_value);
```

or:

```
$("#element_id").attr("data-href", new_value);
```

Comment: No problem.  You can click the checkmark too next to my answer and it will tell people you got the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="testdiv" class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/petsandfashion?fref=ts" data-width="400" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

To get Data Attributes use:

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").getAttribute("data-href");
```

To set Data Attribute use:

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").setAttribute("data-href", "val");
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhv7V/1/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** I added id to the div for demo purpose.

Comment: user3162916. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pure javascript:**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("div_id");
elem.setAttribute("data-href", new_value);
```